# virtualenv to path on Windows 10

Tags: python, path, virtualenv

I have installed virtualenv (if I type "pip list" there is virtualenv (15.1.0)) and when I try to use it throws an error:

> virtualenv : The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> ```
> + virtualenv  
> + ~~~~~~~~~~  
>    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

I think I need to add virtualenv to path, which I've tried without success.

Comment: what version of python/pip are you using? `pip --version`

Comment: Python 3.6.3, pip 9.0.1

Comment: What about `python -m virtualenv`?

Comment: This one works. By the way, what does -m stand for?

Comment: Is there anyway to make "$ virtualenv" work? I mean, it's easier to type just "virtualenv" instead of "python -m virtualenv".

Answer (score 37):

To install :

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

To create a virtual environment (venv):

```
python -m virtualenv venv
```

To activate:

```
-cd venv
-cd Scripts
-activate.bat
```

to deactivate:

```
-deactivate.bat
```

to run venv again just type activate.bat

Note: had problems with the platformio  integrated terminal, used cmd from within the folder.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

1. create a virtual environment

   > python -m virtualenv demoEnv
2. Activate the environment

   > demoEnv\Scripts\activate
3. To deactivate

   > deactivate

Answer (score 2):

```
PS> python -m venv venv
```

If you’re using Python on Windows and you haven’t configured the PATH and PATHEXT variables, then you might need to provide the full path to your Python executable:

```
PS> C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python -m venv venv
```

**Activate It**

```
PS> venv\Scripts\Activate

(venv) PS>
```

**Install Packages Into It**

```
(venv) PS> python -m pip install <package-name>
```

**Deactivate It**

```
(venv) PS> deactivate

PS>
```

Answer (score 0):

do ls and see for the files and folders existing within that django folder created

ls

next .\filename or .\folder\filename

this way we can activate the virtual environment
I did

ls

to activate

.\activate

then virtual environment starts

to deactivate

.\deactivate

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it in two ways:

1. Open the Windows Powershell >> Run as administrator >> *type the command*: Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted >> Hit Enter >> Yes to all.
2. pip install virtualenv --user >> python -m virtualenv venv

Answer (score 0):

this will work

Open the Windows Powershell >> Run as administrator >> type the command: Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted >> Hit Enter >> Yes to all.

pip install virtualenv --user >> python -m virtualenv venv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

.\activate.bat

that seems to help on windows11

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).